# Why this warning when going to Root in Debian?

Tags: debian, su

I do `su` and get

```
masi@masi:/etc/openvpn$ su
Password: 
bash: PATH: No such file or directory
```

Settings

- `echo $PATH` as `root` is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
- `echo $PATH` as `masi` is `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`
- My PATH is exported properly in `$HOME/.bashrc` as `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`. My complete `.bashrc` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23178589/).
- Empty `$HOME/.bash_profile`.
- Not sure what can affect in `/root/`.

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports

Comment: Is there something in your `/root/.bashrc`?

Comment: But isn't the line `export MATLAB_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre` commented out?

Comment: @Findus23 Not in `/root/.bashrc`. - - I deleted it now. For some reason, I had put wrong sentence in wrong place.

Comment: Also sourced: .bash_aliases -- any PATH typos in there?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No. The mistake was in `/root/.bashrc` where I had by accident literally `<PATH>` in `MATLAB_JAVA`. - - Findus23 made excellent questions about possible sources of bugs where one hit the correct target so I gave him the acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It seems you are executing `$PATH` as a command somewhere.</strike>

Have you for example written

```
$PATH = string
```

instead of

```
$PATH=string
```

?

As the error appears after login as root I guess it is a *.bashrc* or *.bash_profile* in */root/*

EDIT:
The angle brackets in `export MATLAB_JAVA=<PATH>java-7-openjdk/jre` were interpreted as piping the file `PATH`, which didn't exist.

EDIT 2: As @ilkkachu has mentioned, the mistake I have mentioned will generate a different error:

```
bash: usr/local/bin:[rest of $PATH]: No such file or directory
```

In this case `PATH` was just interpreted as a filename.

Comment: My `$HOME/.bash_profile` is empty. Where in root? - - Nothing apparent in `$HOME/.bashrc` also shared here http://paste.ubuntu.com/23178589/

Comment: `$HOME` as root (so `/root/.bashrc`)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your comment. I had `export MATLAB_JAVA=<PATH>java-7-openjdk/jre` in `/root/.bashrc` which is completely wrong and should not be there.

Comment: Running `$PATH` on the command line would expand the variable and try to find a program with that name, likely resulting in an error message containing the _contents_ of the `PATH` variable.

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks. I haven't considered that.

Comment: @Findus23, try it :)